# LaTeX -- how to read current value of color?

Tags: color, environment-variables

I want to save the current text colour, then change it, then change back to the original. I was thinking of doing something like:

```
\def\oldcolor{old colour here}    % save colour
\color{red}                       % set colour to new colour
Some text                         % arbitrary length text, perhaps with more colour changes
\color{\oldcolor}                 % restore old colour
```

But I can't find what to put in place of "old colour here". How do I read the current value of the colour, or where can I find this information?

Comment: `\current@color` but why not just use a group? `{\color{red} text}` the color will restore at `}`

Comment: Your code works unless I misunderstood what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle! Will groups work around arbitrary blocks of LaTeX, e.g. could I put a list in there? Please could you copy your comment into an answer, so I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: Yes, although probably you should accept herbert's answer. You can but arbitrary content in a group but for very large sections the colorlet version (added by xcolor not in the original color package) is probably better, and it's  closer to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{green}             % set color
\colorlet{oldcolor}{.}    % save current colour, internally named as .
\color{red}               % set colour to new colour
Some text                 
\color{oldcolor}          % restore old colour    
Some text    
\end{document}
```

[image]