# Get current value of \arrayrulecolor for a colortbl

Tags: colortbl

I want to define a special `tabular` environment and allow the user to specify the colors of the text and the rules independently of their values for a regular `tabular` environment.  For the text color, that's easy, but I can't figure out how to do it for the rules.  Here's a highly simplified example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% Set default colors
\def\xtablerulecolor{black}
\def\xtabletextcolor{black}

% Make color of rules easier to see
\arrayrulewidth0.5mm

\newenvironment{xtable}%
    {%
        % save current value of \arrayrulecolor
        %\gdef\origarrayrulecolor{???}%
        \arrayrulecolor{\xtablerulecolor}%
        \color{\xtabletextcolor}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|}%
    }%
    {%
        \end{tabular}%
        % restore \arrayrulecolor
        %\arrayrulecolor{\origarrayrulecolor}%
    }%

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\xtablerulecolor}{blue}
\renewcommand{\xtabletextcolor}{green}

\arrayrulecolor{red}
\color{magenta}

\texttt{xtable}:

\medskip

\begin{xtable}
    A\\
    B
\end{xtable}    

\bigskip

\texttt{tabular}:
Rules should be red

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
    X\\
    Y
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image: output of code]

The color of the text is local to the `xtable`, which is good, but the `arrayrulecolor` is not.  So I could get the current value of that color before starting the `tabular` environment defined by `xtable` and restore it after ending the environment, along the lines of the code commented out in the example.  But how can I get the current value of `\arrayrulecolor`?  (That is, what should `???` in the code be?)

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254870/latex-how-to-read-current-value-of-color) is related.  Do I need the analogue of `\colorlet` for `\arrayrulecolor`?

Comment: you could save and restore a color that you then pass to `\arrayrulecolor` or you could save and globally restore `\CT@arc@`

Comment: yes was writing an answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Deleted my comment when I saw your answer, before I saw your second comment --- sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save and restore `\CT@arc@`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% Set default colors
\def\xtablerulecolor{black}
\def\xtabletextcolor{black}

% Make color of rules easier to see
\arrayrulewidth0.5mm

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xtable}%
    {%
        % save current value of \arrayrulecolor
        %\gdef\origarrayrulecolor{???}%
        \global\let\saved@CT@arc@\CT@arc@
        \arrayrulecolor{\xtablerulecolor}%
        \color{\xtabletextcolor}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|}%
    }%
    {%
        \end{tabular}%
        % restore \arrayrulecolor
        %\arrayrulecolor{\origarrayrulecolor}%
        \global\let\CT@arc@\saved@CT@arc@
    }%
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\xtablerulecolor}{blue}
\renewcommand{\xtabletextcolor}{green}

\arrayrulecolor{red}
\color{magenta}

\texttt{xtable}:

\medskip

\begin{xtable}
    A\\
    B
\end{xtable}    

\bigskip

\texttt{tabular}:
Rules should be red

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
    X\\
    Y
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey David, what is this `\CT@arc@`?

Comment: @Math122 internal colortbl command holding the array rule color, hence `CT@ a r c @`

Comment: Ok thanks but are you able to tell me why this doesn't work: 
`\let\currentarcolor\arrayrulecolor
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\arrayrulecolor{\currentarcolor}`

Comment: And why if I write `\begingroup \arrarulecolor{red} \endgroup` then still all following tables has red color rules?

Comment: sorry this isn't how the site works, make a real exampe as a new question. array rule color probably a global setting, I don't have the sources to hand on this phone